# How can I convert a map with array values to the list of strings in elegant way?

Tags: elixir

I have a map (errors of `Ecto.Changeset`) like that:

```
%{
  field_a: ["error 1", "error 2"],
  field_b: ["something here"]
}
```

I want it to be a

```
[
  "field_a error 1",
  "field_a error 2",
  "field_b something here"
]
```

I tried to implement it with

```
Enum.map(map, fn({ key, errors }) ->
  # another anonymous function which generates strings
end)
```

but got a compilation error since [elixir doesn't support nested anonymous functions right now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888797/how-do-i-call-an-anonymous-function-inside-enum-map).

How can I implement this convertation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can use `Enum.flat_map`, I believe a `for` would be clearer here:

```
errors = %{
  field_a: ["error 1", "error 2"],
  field_b: ["something here"]
}

formatted =
  for {field, messages} <- errors,
      message <- messages,
      do: "#{field} #{message}"

IO.inspect formatted
```

Output:

```
["field_a error 1", "field_a error 2", "field_b something here"]
```

---

> but got a compilation error since elixir doesn't support nested anonymous functions right now.

That's for anonymous *recursive* functions; Elixir supports nested anonymous functions just fine.